# loring tu proposition 23.4 help

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, solution-verification, proof-explanation, smooth-manifolds

Suppose $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $suppf\subseteq U$ is compact. Then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $U$.

Put $k=suppf$.

The proof starts of by saying: "Being continuous on a compact set, $f$ is bounded."

However, wouldn't this imply that the function $f|_{K}$, is bounded, as opposed to $f$?

Obviously, by Heine Borel, $suppf$ is closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now Loring attempts to show that the extension of $f$; $\hat{f}$, is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n$. This is easy to show, but then he sais that this implies (by Lebesgue's theorem) that $f$ is integrable on $U$. My point is that, by Lebesgue's theorem, $f|_{K}$ is integrable, not necessarily $f$.

What am I missing?

Comment: If $f$ is bounded on $K$ it is also bounded on $U$ since it is $0$ outside $K$. (Assuming that $K$ refers to the support of $f$)

Comment: @leoli1 may you also please answer my question in the comments to Yuvals answer

Answer (score 2):

$K=$supp$f$ is a compact set and $f(x)=0$ for $x \in U \setminus K$ by the definition of support.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)

If the ball $B(x,R)$ contains $K$ then the integral of $f$   on $U \cap B(x,R)$ does not depend on $R$ or $x$, so you can define the integral of $f$ on $U$ as this common value.

Comment: of course! thanks

Comment: With regards to my other question, $U$ is not bounded and Riemann integration is defined on bounded sets, but Loring claims that $f$ is Riemann Integrable on $U$.

Comment: So just to clarify, the following is a definition: If $f:U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function and $U$ is open, if $suppf\subseteq U$ and $suppf$ is compact, then we define $\int_{U}f=\int_{supp f}f$ provided the integral exists, and say that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $U$. Right?

Comment: I meant say $f$ is bounded

Comment: This would work, though as you say usually the (proper) Riemann integral is only defined on bounded sets. I don't know what definition your textbook used.

Comment: The textbook I'm using is Loring Tu's book,intro to manifolds, he defines the Riemann integral on bounded functions on closed rectangles. Then he defines integrals of $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $A$ is bounded and $f$ bounded by their extension, $\hat{f}$, which is 0 outside $A$ and in $A$, $f$ and said $\int_{A}f=\int_{R}\hat{f}$ provided it exists and R is a closed rectangle enclosing $A$. But he doesn't define them for arbitrary sets. So the definition above is the definition I constructed